# Viewing Google Chrome (v69+) Cache on macOS?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently viewed an image from Imgur on Google Chrome for Mac. The image is no longer available, and I would like to fish it out of my cache. `chrome://cache` no longer works. Looking through the files in my library/cache/google folder, I see that the files have no extension and are relatively new.

Doesn't Chrome keep image cache for at least 30 days? If so, how do I access it? Is there a viewer where I can see which files are images?

Comment: As a follow up to this question, I asked a similar one here regarding how to view the extracted data files https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361489/how-to-view-files-within-the-chrome-cache-data-folder

Answer (score 4):

Both `chrome://cache` and `chrome://view-http-cache` have been removed starting chrome 66.

You can find them in

```
~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default
```

All you Chrome activity is saved here `chrome://chrome-urls/`. I just visited Imgur to test and open a image and found this in the `chrome://history/`.

When you click on it it opens it:

[image]

It supposedly keeps the history for 90 Days, but have not tested that.