# How to view files within the Chrome Cache data folder

Tags: google-chrome

I am attempting to perform an examination of the files stored in Google Chrome’s cache folder on Mac OS X. These files were copies from another computer’s cache folder.

The files are all random names with no extension. Is there a forensics or analysis tool that will allow me to view these files?
I have thought about renaming them all to include a jpg extension, but that would be very messy.

There is also a cache index file in a separate folder, but I am unable to read it to extract the list. If there was a way to extract the list, I could write a tool to properly rename the files in the cache folder.

Are there tools for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!